# Javascript/Java How to creat an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java

I am a student learning java and javascript and I'm confused about one of the classes I'm trying to create. I want to make an array list of objects I have created which have information in them. So for example, I have an object that includes its name, birthday, age, sex, hair color, etc. I want to add that object into an array list so how would I do that?

If you need more specifics I can provide them
Thank You

Comment: Java and javascript are very different.  Which one are you working in?

Comment: Please add your example code here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to read about the specifics of this community. Start here [help]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example.

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
Person fred = new Person(...);
people.add(fred);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning create simple POJO:

```
public class myObject{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //etc

public myObject(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

Initialize your array list and object:

```
myObject obj = new myObject("John", 50);
ArrayList<myObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Put your object into array list

```
arrayList.add(obj);
```

I hope this example will help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on initialization

```
yourObject o = new yourObject();
ArrayList<yourObject> a = new ArrayList<yourObject>(Arrays.asList(o));
```

Or:

`a.add(o)`;